# OpenGL changing/reloading textures

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

```
glDeleteTextures(total, &Item::texture[0]);
glGenTextures(total, &Item::texture[0]);
```

Iteration for all images, total;

```
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Item::texture[i] );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits() );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
```

Tries to reload the textures, however it does not. Textures stay the same, unchanged. Any ideas how this could/should be handled? For clarity, I'm trying to reload a texture with a new one, preferably without changing the number of the texture (since there can be a lot of changes).

I'm working with Qt, C++. The code above is in a static function in a seperate GLwidget.

Comment: The interesting thing is that you always delete the texture at index 0 and generates a new one at the same index (0), but then you bind the texture at index `i`. Something smells funny..

Comment: @karlphillip `total` is the count of textures and the second parameter the array start pointer. But why delete and recreate the textures again and again when just the data changes?

Comment: Mmm.. you might be right, gonna check that out.

Comment: So how can I change the data in an other way than deleting and creating then?

Comment: Any chance you're bound to the wrong rendering context, or no rendering context at all, when you're making these calls?

Comment: That might be the case indeed, I think that could be the problem!

Comment: @Nathan That solved it indeed, if you supply an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: @KajToet just bind and call `glTexImage2D` or `glTexSubImage2D`, but well, problem solved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any chance you're bound to the wrong rendering context, or no rendering context at all, when you're making these calls?